# Set of dict values

Tags: python

I have the following dict:

```
d = {'a': set([1,2,3]), 'b': set([3,4,5])}
```

How would I get a set of the unique values, that is, `set([1,2,3,4,5])`

So far I have:

```
all_values = set([])
for item in d.values():
    all_values = all_values.union(item)

>>> all_values
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: @msw Generally when people ask for a "one-liner" what they really mean is a single expression, i.e. a functional approach that avoids mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use list comprehension.

```
>>> d = {'a': set([1,2,3]), 'b': set([3,4,5])}
>>> set([j for i in d.values() for j in i])
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: I would like to understand how your solution works but my comprehension list syntax knowledge seems to be not good enough. Would you mind to give me some hints how this works? Thanks in advance, Frank

Comment: @FrankMartin create a chat room for me and you. I'll explain on that.

Comment: Here is the link to the room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89682/frank-alc

Answer (score 4):

You can unpack the `dict.values()` into `set.union()`. Example -

```
>>> d = {'a': set([1,2,3]), 'b': set([3,4,5])}
>>>
>>> set.union(*d.values())
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: This is the neatest solution. :)

Comment: There's no need to create an empty set to call `union` on: `set.union(*d.values())` works just fine too.

Comment: Yes, thats even better , have added that to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After stopping overthinking it, the following solution is obvious and the shortest (20 chars) and fastest yet at 436ns:

```
d['a'].union(d['b'])
Out[62]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

itertools.chain.from_iterable flattens a nested iterable and performs very well, so one way to do it is:

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
Out[20]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

reduce(func, seq) continually applies the function func to the sequence seq accumulating the result in a single value, so if func(x,y) is x.union(y) and seq is a list of sets the result will be their union.  Expressing func(x,y) as a lambda and using Python 2.7 so there is no need to import functools:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), d.values())
Out[21]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Using Python 3.4.3 the same reduce function works after importing it from functools:

```
import sys
sys.version
Out[6]: '3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'

from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), d.values())
Out[8]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

%timeit performance comparison using Python 2.7.10 shows d['a'].union(d['b']) is fastest, followed by set.union(*d.values()), set(chain.from_iterable(d.values())), reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), d.values()) and set([j for i in d.values() for j in i]). Here are the results in order of increasing execution time:

```
%timeit d['a'].union(d['b'])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 436 ns per loop

%timeit set.union(*d.values())
1000000 loops, best of 3: 763 ns per loop

%timeit set().union(*d.values())
1000000 loops, best of 3: 828 ns per loop

%timeit set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 917 ns per loop

%timeit reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), d.values())
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 µs per loop

%timeit set([j for i in d.values() for j in i])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.54 µs per loop
```

Comment: Should be noted that this won't work in Python 3.X as lambdas in 3.X only take one parameter.

Comment: @IanAuld lambdas in python 3.x can take any number of parameters.

Comment: @IanAuld: I note it works with Python 3.4.3 based on actual testing. According to earlier 3.1 documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/expressions.html#lambda, lambda parameter lists are identical to those for functions as specified in https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/compound_stmts.html#function and includes no explicit limit on the number of parameters.

Comment: Weird, the 2to3 docs state that 3 won't unpack the tuple into separate arguments.

Comment: @IanAuld It means that you cannot do something like - `lambda (x,y): <something else>` . When you call that lambda function, you should pasa a single argument, (that can be a tuple or list or so) , and it gets automatically unpacked into `x` and `y` . That was possible in python 2 , but not possible in python 3.x .

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*d.values()))
```